# Trying to batch decrement values in firestore transaction

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to loop over an array of user objects in my Firestore database, and decrement a `queuePosition` that is associated with them. I am doing this using a transaction. However, I can't quite get it to work. This is my current attempt:

```
function decrementPosition(users, eventId) {
    return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return Promise.all(users.forEach(user => {
            const queuerRef = firebase.db.collection("events")
                                .doc(eventId)
                                .collection("queue")
                                .doc(user.id)
            return transaction.get(queuerRef)
                    .then(doc => {
                        const newPosition = doc.data().queuePosition - 1
                        return transaction.update(queuerRef, {queuePosition: newPosition})
                    })
        }))
    })
}
```

This produces the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`.

Comment: Have you tried using `map` instead of `forEach`?  Another option would be to use `transaction.getAll`.  However, this requires a list of users, rather than an array.

Comment: @JasonBerryman I will try that. Is there any benefit to fitting all the transactions inside one `runTransaction` call compared to the forEach loop creating many individual `Transactions`?

Comment: The transaction document locks the document to ensure that it doesn't get altered anywhere else. I haven't tried performing multiple `transaction.get` within a single transaction, so I don't know how Cloud Firestore will react to that.  Try the `map` command and see how you get on.  If that works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.  If not, I'll see if I can come up with something using `getAll`